# Laravel Elixir Sass Compilation - .sass files

Tags: laravel, sass, laravel-elixir

I'm a bigger fan of `.sass` syntax over the `.scss` syntax (because it's better, let the war begin!), so that's what I'm trying to use. When trying to compile a `.sass` file with Elixir, however, it seems to be trying to use `scss` syntax to compile.

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.sass('styles.sass');
});
```

When `styles.sass` is

```
body
  background: black
```

I get the following errors:

```
$ gulp
[17:54:43] Using gulpfile ~/sites/skynet/gulpfile.js
[17:54:43] Starting 'default'...
[17:54:43] Starting 'sass'...
[17:54:43] Finished 'default' after 185 ms
[17:54:43] gulp-notify: [Laravel Elixir] Error: invalid top-level expression
[17:54:43] Finished 'sass' after 198 ms
```

But changing `styles.sass` (still keeping the `.sass` extension), to

```
body {
  background: black;
}
```

I get a successful compilation. Does Elixir only compile `scss` syntax or am I missing some sort of config setup? Help much appreciated!

Comment: After some experimentation, I found that it only compiles assets in the `sass` directory using `.scss` syntax. Boy that's confusing! One would expect a `sass` directory to contain `.sass` files and vice versa...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **@mul14**, I looked deeper into the different libraries that gulp-sass relies on. The issue on github was a discussion that eventually led to someone successfully supporting the indentation syntax and it getting merged into libsass.

After looking into node-sass's documentation, I found an [option](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#indentedsyntax) for turning on indented syntax. Looking at Elixir's sass ingredient arguments, this worked for me!

```
elixir(function(mix) {
  mix.sass('styles.sass', false, { indentedSyntax: true });
});
```

So, in the end it was a config issue. Great news for indented syntax users around the globe!

Answer (score 0):

That's because Laravel Elixir use [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass). And the inside of gulp-sass it use [node-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass). The node-sass use [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass), which is does not support .sass file https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/16

You can use [gulp-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ruby-sass) to compile .sass to css. Or use the [laravel-elixir-ruby-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-elixir-ruby-sass).

Comment: That issue on github was hard to follow... At the beginning people want sass support, at the end https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/16#issuecomment-45261578? Didn't it get merged in?